# Can i use APNS/GCM for implementing an Instant messaging service iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I need to set up an instant messaging service in ios/android application, using phonegap. Since, its not an app for chat, but it just have a ,messaging service. Can i use push notification service to implement instant messaging in foreground. It works fine, when i developed a demo. Will apple reject the app because of this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. Remember gcm/apns have a limit and you got to paid when quota exceed.

It is also discussed in other thread

[Is it good to use only GCM for developing chat applications for android ditching XMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637118/is-it-good-to-use-only-gcm-for-developing-chat-applications-for-android-ditching)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that on iOS user can forbid sending remote notifications, in which case your chat won't work even in foreground.